# Angular Mat checkbox - pass selected rows to the backend logic

Tags: node.js, angular, api, checkbox, angular-material

I'm using Angular material data tables and I'm able to use selected rows propreties for handling data in the frontend like export rows to csv format,
I have a node.js api that updates the current status of an item and i'm using this API in my angular service
I'm able to modify the status for a single item from the details page ,
but I want to have the possibility to modify it for all the items after checking all the rows ,

Any idea on how that can be done

Comment: Can you explain bit properly. 
You can use mat table checkboxes to update the status, in backend too.

Comment: i can modify the status of each item seperately by clicking on a button in the details page.Iwant to implement this button in the home page to be able to modify multiple items at the same time